# Constructor, initializer list and different behaviour in g++ and clang

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, g++, initializer-list

This is the simplified code:

```
#include <vector>

class VInitList
{
public:
    explicit VInitList(std::vector<int> v){}
};

int main()
{
    VInitList vil({{}});
}
```

and compiling with g++ 5.2.1 a get this error:

```
 error: call of overloaded ‘VInitList(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
     VInitList vil({{}});
                       ^
main.cpp:6:5: note: candidate: VInitList::VInitList(std::vector<int>)
     VInitList(std::vector<int> v){}
     ^
main.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: constexpr VInitList::VInitList(const VInitList&)
     class VInitList
           ^
main.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: constexpr VInitList::VInitList(VInitList&&)
```

When I saw the compiler error I found out that I have written `{{}}` by mistake (yeah, don't be mean to me), but I still cannot understand the error. IMHO either the compiler must get rid of the extra {} or return a syntax error.

Then I tried to compile this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {{{}}};
```

which works as intended.

Comment: I only glanced over your example, but you got an extra pair of brackets on the code snippet that did compile, maybe that is why?

Comment: It does not compile in g++ 5.2.1 but it does in Clang 3.7.0

Comment: Interesting Q. It seems that, in your scenario, single `{}` are enough in both the cases. The contained type is `int`, why to complicate? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But `std::vector<int> v = {{{}}};` doesn't do what you think; it initializes a vector with one `int` element, initialized to zero. This is because `int` can be list-initialized:

```
int i{};   // assert(i == 0)
```

So `std::vector<int> v = {{{}}};` is parsed as:

```
std::vector<int> v = {{{}}};
                       ^-- int
                      ^-- initializer_list<int>
                     ^-- vector<int>
```

Likewise, if you write

```
VInitList vil{{{}}};
               ^-- int
              ^-- vector<int>
             ^-- VInitList
```

the contained `vector<int>` has 1 element, initialized to zero. (The `initializer_list<int>` stage can be omitted because the `vector(initializer_list<int>)` constructor is non-`explicit`).

So `VInitList vil({{}});` could be parsed as:

```
VInitList vil({{}});
               ^-- int
              ^-- vector<int>
```

or as

```
VInitList vil({{}});
               ^-- vector<int>
              ^-- VInitList
```

In the first case the `vector` has 1 element; in the second case it's empty. It's just as well that gcc rejects your code.

Clang only parses it as the former; I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: very interesting, I didn't know int can be list-initialized. why is that possible? and what for?

Comment: @FrankS101 consistency, mainly - it means you can use `{}` or `= {}` anywhere you want an object initialized to its "empty" state. Note that in C++98 you could use `()` in places it wouldn't be confused with a function declaration, e.g. member initializers: `struct S { int i; S() : i() {} };`